# Java отличие инициализации от конструктора

Tags: java

В чем разница между этими двумя конструкциями. Или если переформулировать вопрос, то зачем нужны блоки инициализации, если есть всем привычный конструктор без параметров?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Динамический блок — это добавка для упрощения написания конструктора, и он не приносит дополнительной функциональности. Он позволяет сэкономить создание функции запуска и добавление её вызова из всех конструкторов. Например, фрагмент кода:

```
public class Car {
    static int count = 0;
    public Car (String model) {
        init();
        // ...
    }
    public Car (String model, Double price) {
        init();
        // ...
    }

    private void init() {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Hello everyone, we have " + count + " cars now!");
    }
    // ...
}
```

равнозначен коду:

```
public class Car {
    static int count = 0;
    public Car (String model) {
        // ...
    }
    public Car (String model, Double price) {
        // ...
    }

    {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Hello everyone, we have " + count + " cars now!");
    }
    // ...
}
```

[Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)